# is this a correct way to use Notification Center to execute tasks in a certain order avoiding memory leaks?

Tags: swift, closures, notificationcenter

I'm testing the usage of notifications and completion handlers to perform multiple time consuming tasks in a certain order. A colleague told me to check for possible memory leaks.

My questions are:

- my LongTasksClass: is this a proper way to use notifications and closures?
- is it correct to not remove observers after iOS 9?
- should be better make a singleton launched elsewhere?

in my view controller I have:

```
private var longTaskInstance: LongTasksClass? = LongTasksClass()
```

and in a button:

```
longTaskInstance?.startOperation()
```

my class

```
class LongTasksClass {
    
    enum TestingEnum: String {
        case firstOperation
        case secondOperation
        case stop
    }
    
    //public
    let testNotification = NSNotification.Name("test")
    
    //private
    private var myStatus: TestingEnum = .firstOperation
    private let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    
    
    init() {
        
        notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: self.testNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
            guard let self = self else {return}
            print(notification.userInfo?["info", default: "N/D"] ?? "no userInfo")
            
            self.doWholeOperation() {
                //first calls code in comletion
                //then calls this
                print("code after last completion")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    func startOperation() {
        notificationCenter.post(name: self.testNotification, object: nil, userInfo: ["info" : "info start operation"])
    }
    
    //MARK: - private section -
    
    private func doWholeOperation(_ completion: @escaping (()) -> () ) {
        
        switch myStatus {
        case .firstOperation:
            print("very start: \(Date())\n")
            firstTimeConsumingTask { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else {return}
                print("end first: \(Date())\n")
                self.myStatus = .secondOperation
                self.notificationCenter.post(name: self.testNotification, object: nil, userInfo: ["info" : "info sent from first task"])
            }
        case .secondOperation:
            secondTimeConsumingTask {
                print("end second: \(Date())\n")
                self.myStatus = .stop
                self.notificationCenter.post(name: self.testNotification, object: nil, userInfo: ["info" : "info sent from second task"])
            }
        case .stop:
            myStatus = .firstOperation
            let myCodeForCompletion: () = print("very end")
            completion(myCodeForCompletion)
            return
        }
    }
    
    private func firstTimeConsumingTask(_ completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        print("start first task: \(Date())")
        //simulating long task
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            print("inside first task: \(Date())")
            completion()
        }
    }
    
    private func secondTimeConsumingTask(_ completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
        print("start second task: \(Date())")
        //simulating long task
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            print("inside second task: \(Date())")
            completion()
        }
    }
    
    //should not be required aymore
    deinit {
        print("‼️ called deinit")
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must unregister notification observers created by `addObserver(forName:object:queue:using)`. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver):

> Return Value: An opaque object to act as the observer. Notification center strongly holds this return value until you remove the observer registration.

> You must invoke `removeObserver(_:)` or `removeObserver(_:name:object:)` before the system deallocates any object that `addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)` specifies.

This `removeObserver` is called on the returned value from `addObserver` (which you must store). It is not called on `self`. The point of the `addObserver(forName:object:queue:using)` is that it creates an opaque object observer; it does not make `self` an observer.

Regarding iOS 9, you're thinking of [`addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver), which makes the first parameter (usually `self`) an observer, and generally does not require unregistering:

> If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, you do not need to unregister an observer that you created with this function. If you forget or are unable to remove an observer, the system cleans up the next time it would have posted to it.

As always, consult the documentation.

Your `deinit` is incorrect (as you suspect). The call you make is not required, but you lack the required call to remove the observation you do make.

As a general rule, the selector-based API is much easier to use correctly. People tend to just have a fondness for block-based APIs even when they're less convenient.

In your example, the code required is:

```
class LongTasksClass {
...
    var observer: NSObjectProtocol
...
   init() {
        observer = notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: self.testNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] notification in
            ...   
        }     
    }
    ...
    deinit {
        notificationCenter.removeObserver(observer)
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but starting from your answer, which is a correct way to remove the observer? And where should it be if not in the deinit of the class?

Comment: thanks! so in the end I misunderstood that I need to store the result of the method and use that result to remove observers. Probably one would not expect a view controller is conforming to NSObjectProtocol. that's why many use self as default. It is a very important concept. so you think the rest of the code is a good solution?

Comment: View controllers always conform to NSObjectProtocol (since UIViewController conforms to NSObjectProtocol). Using `self` with the **block** form of `addObserver` is impossible. It does not take an "observer" parameter. The block form of `addObserver` **creates** an observer object and returns it. You must then deal with that object. The **selector** form of `addObserver` almost always takes `self` as the observer.

Comment: As for the rest of the code, if I wanted to run three operations in order, I would use a serial GCD queue, OperationQueue, or completion blocks (or in modern Swift, structured concurrency using async/await), not notifications. If your code relies on there being an observer when you post a notification, it is probably wrong. The point of notifications is that they are independent of the number of observers. The poster should be comfortable with any number (including 0) observers. The fact that your notification is handled by the same function that posted it is a good sign it's overcomplicated.